# Global Update (All Rows) On One SQL Table With The Same Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

IS there a way to run this across every column in a table:

```
UPDATE dbo.stage_a
SET Statement_Name= NULL
WHERE Statement_Name='""';
```

I am trying to tidy up after a data import.

Comment: What do you mean by run this across every column ? You can use `,` and mention the column name. If you want do it dynamically  then select all columns from schema and then create dynamic query and execute it.

Comment: The table has 60 columns, I'm looking to run it across the whole table to replace all instance of '""' with NULLS.

Comment: There's no general UPDATE allcolumns, you'll to build the UPDATE statement(s) using the data dictionary's column info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dynamic query` plus `Information_schema.columns`. Try this.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max)='UPDATE dbo.stage_a set '

SELECT @cols += COLUMN_NAME + '=case when ' + COLUMN_NAME
                + ' = '""' then null else '+COLUMN_NAME+' end,'
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'stage_a'
       AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'

SELECT @cols = LEFT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)

PRINT @cols

EXEC Sp_executesql @cols
```

Comment: This runs (needed to exclude the auto-id) column. But the data in the table remains the same. The data I'm trying to replace is "".

Comment: Fixed, replaced '''' with ''""'' - worked perfectly. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Customers
SET ContactName='Alfred Schmidt', City='Hamburg'
WHERE CustomerName='Alfreds Futterkiste';
```

Like this example you should specify all coloumns.(separated by commas)

If you want to replace all coloumns with NULL why don't you delete the rows:

```
DELETE FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName='Alfreds Futterkiste'
```

Answer (score 0):

You meed to first get the all columns list by using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

```
   DECLARE @tableName varchar(10)
   SET @tableName = 'mm'

   DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
   SET @sql = ''

   SELECT @sql = @sql + 'UPDATE ' + @tableName + ' SET ' + c.name + ' = NULL WHERE ' + c.name + '= ''';'
   FROM sys.columns c
   INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
   INNER JOIN sys.types y ON c.system_type_id = y.system_type_id
   WHERE t.name = @tableName AND y.name IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar')

  EXEC (@sql)
```

Query is not tested may need to tweak as per your need